# Customizing the label of vcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, vcf-vcard

I am using gem "vcard". How can I customize the name of URL to read it as Skype/linkedin.

My code is like

```
card = Vcard::Vcard::Maker.make2 do |maker|
    maker.add_url(linkedin_url) if linkedin_url
end
```

This is coming within "other" in card. I want this "other" to come as "linkedin".

Answer (score 0):

```
 card = Vcard::Vcard::Maker.make2 do |maker|
      maker.add_field(::Vcard::DirectoryInfo::Field.create("item1.URL", '', "type" => "pref:linked in_url value"))  
      maker.add_field(::Vcard::DirectoryInfo::Field.create("item1.X-ABLabel", 'Linkedin Url'))

end
```